# FilenotFoundException while attaching xlsx but not for txt file in java/rest assured

Tags: java, excel, attachment, rest-assured

I am exploring Java and RestAssured, where I was trying to attach a document to my bug in JIRA.

While I was able to attach a text file successfully(jira.txt), I re-executed the code to attach the excel and I get FilenotFoundException error while trying to insert an excel file format.

But, both the document path is under the same root folder of project-JIRA-API.
Please advise.

Here is a snippet: (the code runs fine when it is "jira.txt" )

//Add an attachment

```
     System.out.println("\n\n...............ADD AN ATTACHMENT TO BUG..........\n\n");
     given().log().all().header("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check").filter(session)
     .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
     .multiPart("file",new File("API.xlsx"))
     .when().post("rest/api/2/issue/"+id+"/attachments")
     .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

( link below for code screenshot)[code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn9Gq.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to deal with file path:

Solution 1:

- Put the file in `src/test/resources`
- Code will be `.multiPart("file",new File("src/test/resources/API.xlsx"))`

Solution 2:

- Put the file in working directory
- Code will be `.multiPart("file",new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/API.xlsx"))`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you.
I still faced FileNotfound exception for both of above.
However, when I gave the link from my system directory now, it surprisingly worked.

But, I am still trying to figure out on the exception/issue while trying to attach from eclipse directory. Because it works for txt file. Not sure what am I missing out for the excel format.

Code:

```
 //Add an attachment
     
     System.out.println("\n\n...............ADD AN ATTACHMENT TO BUG..........\n\n");
     File testUploadFile= new File ("E:\\API learning\\API.xlsx");
             
     given().log().all().header("X-Atlassian-Token","no-check").filter(session)
     .header("Content-Type","multipart/form-data")
     .pathParam("id", "10101")
    // .multiPart("file",new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/API.xlsx"))
     .multiPart(testUploadFile)
     .when().post("rest/api/2/issue/{id}/attachments")
     .then().log().all().assertThat().statusCode(200);
```

Comment: If it doesn't works even with answer on your question, you can edit your main question, and post comment to people about the part that you add, which doesn't work